# How to parse rss feed in xml format instead of json format from url - Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, json, xml, ionic-framework, rss

I downloaded the `xml2json` library from the `npm` and then installed the `typings` but still I'm getting something wrong with the code, I see that the data has been parsed in the console but it is not displayed in the `ion-list`.

`rss-service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as x2js  from 'xml2json';

@Injectable()
export class RssService {

  public xml2js: any = [];

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello RssService Provider');
  }

  load() {

      return Observable.create(s => {
          this.http.get('url.xml')
           .map(res => res.text())
           .subscribe(data => {
             var posts = JSON.stringify(data);
             x2js.parseString(posts, function (err, result) {
               console.log(posts);
             });
           }, error => {
                 console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
              }); 
          });
     }
}
```

`home.ts` - `home.html`

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RssService } from '../../providers/rss-service/rss-service';
import { DetailPage } from '../detail-page/detail-page';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers: [RssService]
})
export class HomePage {

  doRefresh(refresher) {
    console.log('Begin async operation', refresher);

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Async operation has ended');
      refresher.complete();
    }, 2000);
  }

  public entries: any  = [];

  constructor(public rssService:RssService, public nav:NavController) {    
  }

  ionViewDidLoad(){
      this.rssService.load().subscribe(
          data => {
              this.entries.push(data);
          }
      );
  } 

  openPage(entry) {
      console.log('open page called with ' + entry.title);
      this.nav.push(DetailPage, {selectedEntry:entry});
  }

}

<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title text-center>
      App Name
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content></ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>
     <ion-list>
       <ion-item *ngFor="let entry of entries" (click)="openPage(entry)" text-wrap>
            <h2 class="feed-title">{{entry.title}}</h2>
       </ion-item>
     </ion-list>
 </ion-content>
```

**Edit**

I've also tried using `DOMParser` and I'm able to display in the console an array of `<item>` where each of them contain `<title>`, `<description>`, `<pubDate>`, `<enclosure>`, `<link>` but can't display them in the `ion-list`.

Could you help me?

```
load() {

return Observable.create(s => {
  this.http.get('url.xml')
  .map(res => res.text())
  .subscribe(data => {
    if(data) {
      var parser = new DOMParser();
      var xmlData = parser.parseFromString(data, "application/xml");
      var items = xmlData.querySelectorAll("item");
      for (var index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
        var element = items[index];
        console.log(element);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

This is the xml I'm trying to parse

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title><![CDATA[Site Name Home]]></title>
    <link>http://www.my-site.it/home</link>
    <description><![CDATA[Site description]]></description>
    <pubDate>Sat, 14 Jan 2017 11:36:51 +0100</pubDate>
    <image>
      <url>http://www.image.it/uploads/../images/rss.jpg</url>
      <title><![CDATA[Site Name]]></title>
      <link>http://www.sitename.it/home</link>
    </image>
    <generator>Zend_Feed</generator>
    <language>en</language>
    <docs>http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/tech/rss</docs>
    <item>
      <title><![CDATA[Title]]></title>
      <link>http://link</link>
      <description><![CDATA[Description]]></description>
      <pubDate>Sat, 14 Jan 2017 10:28:00 +0100</pubDate>
      <enclosure url="http://image-url.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="110"/>
    </item>
    . 
    .
    <item>...</item>
```

in the console I'm getting exactly the array of item shown above

```
<item>
  <title><![CDATA[Title]]></title>
  <link>http://link</link>
  <description><![CDATA[Description]]></description>
  <pubDate>Sat, 14 Jan 2017 10:28:00 +0100</pubDate>
  <enclosure url="http://image-url.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="110"/>
</item>
. 
.
<item>...</item>
```

**Edit 2**

Added your code in `load()`

```
load() {
  return Observable.create(s => {
    this.http.get('url.xml')
    .map(res => res.text())
    .subscribe(data => {
      var parser = new DOMParser();
      var xmlData = parser.parseFromString(data, "application/xml");

      // First get the information (title, description, ...)
      var info = {};
      (xmlData.querySelectorAll("channel>*:not(item)") || []).forEach(function(e){
        var infoData = {};
        var found = false;
        e.childNodes.forEach(function(e){
          // skip text nodes
          if(e.nodeType == 3) return;
          found = true;
          infoData[e.tagName] = e.textContent;
        });
        if(found) info[e.tagName] = infoData;
        else info[e.tagName] = e.textContent;
      });

      // Then, get the list of items
      var items = [];
      (xmlData.querySelectorAll("channel>item") || []).forEach(function(item){
        var itemData = {};
        item.childNodes.forEach(function(e){
          // skip over text nodes
          if(e.nodeType == 3) return;

          // get attributes if exist (to support the 'enclosure' element)
          var attr = {};
          var found = false;
          for(var i = 0, atr = e.attributes, l = e.attributes.length; i < l; i++){
            found = true;
            attr[atr[i].name] = atr[i].value;
          }
          if(found) itemData[e.tagName] = attr;
          else itemData[e.tagName] = e.textContent;
        });
        items.push(itemData);
      });
      console.log("INFO: ", info);
      console.log("ITEMS: ", items);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: If you are writing code for browser, you can try DOMParser https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMParser

Comment: I read the article but how do I implement it with my code?

Comment: `DOMParser` only parses XML into a tree which you manipulate like `document` with `getElementById`, `appendChild` etc. You need to extract information manually so you need to know the format of RSS (which is fairly simple). For example, get title with `tree.querySelector("title").innerText`.

Comment: I made changes to my code as you said but I'm still having some trouble.
If you answer with the proper changes to the code I'll accept

Comment: Here is a mini example:
`async function load() {
      var response = await fetch("http://karpathy.github.io/feed.xml");
      var parser = new DOMParser();
      var text = await response.text();
      var tree = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");
      var items = tree.querySelectorAll("item");
      for (var i = 0, n = items.length; i < n; i++) {
        console.log(items[i]);
      }
    }`

Comment: what is the format of the xml your are using? Can you show an example?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir check the edit in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will generate two objects: `info` which holds informations such as title, description ..., and `items` which is an array of object representing the items.

The names of the properities of these objects are either tag names or attribute names, and they're following the same heirarchy as the XML data. Now since they are objects, it will be easy to access their data for example:

```
// Info object
var title = info.title;
var imgUrl = info.image.url;
//...

// Items array
items.forEach(function(item){
    var itemTitle = item.title;
    var itemEnclosureUrl = item.enclosure.url;
    //...
});
```

```js
var data = '<rss xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" version="2.0"><channel><title>Site Name</title><link>http://www.my-site.it/home</link><description>Site description</description><pubDate>Sat, 14 Jan 2017 11:36:51 +0100</pubDate><image><url>http://www.image.it/uploads/../images/rss.jpg</url><title><![CDATA[Site Name]]></title><link>http://www.sitename.it/home</link></image><generator>Zend_Feed</generator><language>en</language><docs>http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/tech/rss</docs><item><title><![CDATA[Title]]></title><link>http://link</link><description>Description</description><pubDate>Sat, 14 Jan 2017 10:28:00 +0100</pubDate><enclosure url="http://image-url.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="110"/></item></channel></rss>';


var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlData = parser.parseFromString(data, "application/xml");

// First get the information (title, description, ...)
var info = {};
(xmlData.querySelectorAll("channel>*:not(item)") || []).forEach(function(e){
    var infoData = {};
    var found = false;
    e.childNodes.forEach(function(e){
        // skip text nodes
        if(e.nodeType == 3) return;
        found = true;
        infoData[e.tagName] = e.textContent;
    });
    if(found) info[e.tagName] = infoData;
    else info[e.tagName] = e.textContent;
});

// Then, get the list of items
var items = [];
(xmlData.querySelectorAll("channel>item") || []).forEach(function(item){
    var itemData = {};
    item.childNodes.forEach(function(e){
        // skip over text nodes
        if(e.nodeType == 3) return;

        // get attributes if exist (to support the 'enclosure' element)
        var attr = {};
        var found = false;
        for(var i = 0, atr = e.attributes, l = e.attributes.length; i < l; i++){
            found = true;
            attr[atr[i].name] = atr[i].value;
        }
        if(found) itemData[e.tagName] = attr;
        else itemData[e.tagName] = e.textContent;
    });
    items.push(itemData);
});

console.log("INFO: ", info);
console.log("ITEMS: ", items);
```

This will work fine if the XML data was in the form you provided. If it is changed, some of the code have to be changed to adapt to the new format.

This code was based on the assumption that there is one `channel` element in the XML data and that the title and description where not tags as you provided (I assumed the title and description will be text and not tags).

Comment: There are some things I don't understand:

1. you used `var data = '...'` as something that will not change, as I understand but I need to get rss feed from a Url that updates its content

2. Does the code above have to be in `load()` function? Aren't there any changes to the code in `home.ts`? Because as far as I got the problem was not to parse the data from the Url but to display it in the `ion-list`, so I assumed there was something wrong in `home.ts`

Comment: 1) `var data = ...` was there to just get a valid code snippet, in your code you get `data` using `this.http.get('url.xml')...` so data won't be a fixed string. 2) you can add this code to load or you can wrap it in another function (`function parseData(data){...` that take the `data` (xml string) as an argument and then parse it into `info` and `items` objects which you'll then use to create your `ion-list` easely (using `document.createElement(...)`, `....appendChild(...)` `....textContent = ...`);

Comment: I'm getting a _Typescript Error
Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'NodeListOf<Element> | undefined[]'._ at these lines `(xmlData.querySelectorAll("channel>*:not(item)") || []).forEach(function(e){
  var infoData = {};` and `(xmlData.querySelectorAll("channel>item") || []).forEach(function(item){`. I added your code inside `load()` function as you can see above

Comment: If you're using a browser then this should work (all the recent browser support `forEach` on arrays). If not, then this whole code won't work (as there will be no `DOMParser`).

Comment: if you are using or targeting older browsers add this before the code: `Array.prototype.forEach = function(f){for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){ f(this[i], i);}};`

Comment: I'm sorry, I was to hasty to look only at the page that says _Typescript Error Property 'forEach'_ but I opened the console and actually saw the data retrieved, INFO and ITEMS (ITEMS as an Array of objects).
Now I just have to take the items and show them in the ion-list, as soon as I get how to do that I'll give you the bounty